# Flex Box breaking into Columns

Tags: css, flexbox

I need help with my Flex Box Layout. It should break into two columns, with two divs each, the same time, the first smaller Box shifts down.

BTW: What is the correct syntax, to target Child 2 and 3 at once?

```css
#container_left {
  height: 500px;
  /*height for testing*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item_left {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  margin: 0.5%;
  width: 10%;
}

.item_left:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item_left:nth-child(3) {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/*Either for testing*/

div {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_left">
  <div class="item_left"></div>
  <div class="item_left"></div>
  <div class="item_left"></div>
  <div class="item_left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to show your HTML markup too.

Comment: can you please create a snippet of your code

Comment: Create a code pen of this code and paste the url so , that we get a better idea about the code .

Answer (score 0):

Try placing two divs in html for two columns and inside those , place two these four divs (two in each).It will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to target the 2nd and 3rd child of `#container-left`, however, `.item_left:nth-child(2)` will target the 2nd child of elements with the `item-left` class. To target the nth element from `#container-left`, you will need to use `#container-left:nth-child(2)`.

```css
#container_left {
  height: 500px;
  /*height for testing*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item_left {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  margin: 0.5%;
  width: 10%;
}

#container-left:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#container-left:nth-child(3) {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/*Either for testing*/

div {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```